# How can I use DBeaver for a data export for a table with the database Informix and the command unload

Tags: sql, informix, dbeaver

I want to use the database client DBeaver (version 23.1.0) to save certain data from a database table to a file. I use the Informix database version "IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 14.10". I want to use the "unload" command from Informix to save the desired data to a specific file.

Here is the example:
I have the file "germany.unl" in which I want to save the countries from the database table "countries" with the country germany.

I tried it with the following command:

```
UNLOAD TO C:\temp\germany.unl DELIMITER ";"
SELECT * FROM countries WHERE name = "germany"
```

However, I get the following error message in DBeaver:

```
SQL Error [42000]: A syntax error has occurred.
```

So the question arises for me, can the unload command be used for a data export with the database client DBeaver for the database Informix

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that the UNLOAD statement is not implemented by the server but by various front-end tools (such as DB-Access) as a pseudo-SQL statement.  The tools convert that into a SELECT statement that retrieves the data and then do the formatting on the client side.  In particular, that means that if you send an UNLOAD statement to the server, you will get back a syntax error because it is not an SQL statement recognized by the server — and that is probably what you are seeing.  Similar comments apply to the LOAD statement.

Unless DBeaver also does the client-side processing necessary to handle the operation, it will fail.

I don't know what the official DBeaver solution is.  However, there's a decent chance that there is a mechanism that allows you to save the results of a query to a data file in one of a number of formats (probably not including the Informix UNLOAD format, but likely including options such as CCSV or JSON).